# Setting textSize in draw() function of Processing.js results in text disappearing (in Chrome only)

Tags: google-chrome, processing.js

The following processing.js code initially draws a background and text. However, a few seconds later, the text flashes quickly; and a few seconds after that, the text disappears entirely.

```
processing.draw = function() {
    processing.background(0,255,0);
    processing.textSize(20);
    processing.text("Test", 30, 30); 
};
```

The issue seems to be with the [textSize()](http://processingjs.org/reference/textSize_/) function. If you remove that line, the problem disappears. Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bbh9r8bp/12/

Note that this seems isolated to Chrome, since it occurs with v41.0.2272.104 (64-bit), but neither on Safari v8.0.4 nor on Firefox v29.0.1. I am using Processing v1.4.8 in my project, but the issue is the same in the fiddle using v1.4.7. Earlier versions of the library seem to not have this issue (tried with v1.0.0 on jsfiddle and on [Khan Academy's live editor](http://khan.github.io/live-editor/demos/simple/) which seems to have originated with Processing.js 1.2.3 or thereabouts.

This may well be an issue with the Processing library, but it seems like such a simple bug that I must be missing something.

Comment: I looked into this based on your bug report over at https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/issues/167, and have code up that shows it working fine, so it could just be the unusual code that you're using. Want to confirm the jsbin from that issue works for you in Chrome? Because it works quite fine for me. (Also, the current version of Firefox is 36... you *really* want to upgrade, unless you enjoy using a browser with at this point plenty of well documented security vulnerabilities)

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for your help! See my response on github…